# Local function reflection Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I understood how to get declared functions in a class.

Example:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Foo (val name: String)

class Bar {
    fun main() {
        val declaredMethods = this::class.java.declaredMethods

        declaredMethods.filter {
            it.isAnnotationPresent(Foo::class.java)
        }.forEach {
            it.invoke(this)
        }
    }

    @Foo("foo")
    fun baz() {
        println("foo")
    }
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve local functions that have an annotation.

Example:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Foo (val name: String)

@Foo("foo")
fun baz() {
    println("foo")
}
```

Thank you in advance,
Bye

**EDIT FOR Konstantin Raspopov:** Thanks for your answer, sadly my functions are in different files and I don't know the name of the classes.

Comment: You may add `@file:JvmName("Utils")
@file:JvmMultifileClass` annotations to each of your files with functions, then compiler will generate a single Java facade class which has the specified name. Is it possible in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your code is located in file `Hello.kt`, you can do it like this:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Foo (val name: String)

@Foo("foo")
fun baz() {
    println("foo")
}

fun main() {
    val clazz = Class.forName("HelloKt")
    val declaredMethods = clazz.declaredMethods

    declaredMethods.filter {
        it.isAnnotationPresent(Foo::class.java)
    }.forEach {
        it.invoke(clazz)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question. If you have any answer to resolve this issue, I will be glad to read it.